# getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Profile not locked due to exception in eclipse while trying to open Install new software

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I am Using Eclipse Gallileo and once I try to open the install new software , I am getting the error as the install new software window is not opening

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Profile not locked due to exception:
C:\WORK\GALILEO\eclipse_STT - Offline\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry\
epp.package.rcp.profile\.lock (Access is denied)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfileLock.lock(ProfileLock.java:106)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.restore(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:377)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:247)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.internalGetProfile(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:207)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.getProfile(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:137)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.operations.ProvisioningUtil.getProfile(ProvisioningUtil.java:217)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.ProvSDKUIActivator.getSelfProfileId(ProvSDKUIActivator.java:161)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler.execute(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:49)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
  at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
  at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
  at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:770)
  at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$10(CommandContributionItem.java:756)
  at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:746)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3880)
  at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3473)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
  at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
  at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
  at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear to demonstrate the issue by the exception.

You need check whether your account that is running Eclipse has permission to create lock file(**C:\WORK\GALILEO\eclipse_STT - Offline\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry\epp.package.rcp.profile.lock**). Or manually remove it if it already exists.